# How to switch the views form address book to mailing view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, abaddressbook, uimodalpresentationstyle

This might be a trivial thing but I am new to xamarin/monotouch or iPhone/IOS development, 
I am trying to make an application(sort of gallery+mail) in which I want to share the image.At longpress 
it should open the contacts from where I can select the person from contact and it should take me to the 
mailing view. I do not want to do this usung "pushview", but want to just switch the views using "PresentModalViewController"

Now I am getting the addressbook but as soon as I select the contact person instead of displaying the
mailing view it goes back to the homeview.
I even tried dismissing the view after the mailing view is dismissed but the output is still the same..
please help out with this.

what I am doing is as follows:(just merged the two programs given on Xamarin website)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.AddressBookUI;
using MonoTouch.MessageUI;

namespace ChooseContact
{
    public partial class ChooseContactViewController : UIViewController
    {


        public ChooseContactViewController () : base ("ChooseContactViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            ABPeoplePickerNavigationController _contactController;
            UIButton _chooseContact;
            UILabel _contactName;
            _chooseContact = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            _chooseContact.Frame = new RectangleF (10, 10, 200, 50);
            _chooseContact.SetTitle ("Choose a Contact", UIControlState.Normal);
            _contactName = new UILabel{Frame = new RectangleF (10, 70, 200, 50)};

            View.AddSubviews (_chooseContact, _contactName);

            _contactController = new ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ();

            _chooseContact.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                this.PresentModalViewController (_contactController, true); };


            _contactController.SelectPerson += delegate(object sender, ABPeoplePickerSelectPersonEventArgs e) {
                //_contactName.Text = string.Format(e.Person.GetEmails());         
                _contactName.Text = String.Format ("{0} {1}", e.Person.FirstName, e.Person.LastName);

                _contactController.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);

                MFMailComposeViewController _mailController;
                string[] Emailid = {"hz@gmail.com"};

                _mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController ();
                _mailController.SetToRecipients (Emailid);

                _mailController.SetSubject ("mail test");
                _mailController.SetMessageBody ("this is a test", false);
                _mailController.Finished += ( object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) => {

                    Console.WriteLine (args.Result.ToString ());

                    args.Controller.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true); 
                };

                    this.PresentModalViewController (_mailController, true);




            };
        }

        public override void ViewDidUnload ()
        {
            base.ViewDidUnload ();

            // Clear any references to subviews of the main view in order to
            // allow the Garbage Collector to collect them sooner.
            //
            // e.g. myOutlet.Dispose (); myOutlet = null;

            ReleaseDesignerOutlets ();
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            // Return true for supported orientations
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```
_contactController.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
```

Comment: dosent work, it freezes as i select the contact and gives me the following warning:

ChooseContact[499:c07] Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x12369c70> on <ChooseContactViewController: 0xe1eb220> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!